# dict comprehension with range

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a dictionary that gets keys from one dictionary as key, and gets numbers from range() as values. For example, this is what I've tried;

```
files = {'/var/www/test.jgp': 40kb, '/var/www/banner.jgp':40kb}
files_num = dict((key, value) for key in files.keys() for value in range(1, len(files) + 1))
```

Which didn't work. I know this can be done if I create a list of the files.keys() and a list of range(1, len(files) + 1) and then use something like zip. But was wondering if there was a more elegant solution using dict comprehensions.

I'm looking for the output to be something like this:

```
{'/var/www/test.jgp': 1, '/var/www/banner.jgp': 2}
```

Any advice on this (assuming it is possible to do with dict comprehension) would be appreciated).

Comment: Are you trying to make the value of each key stand for some sort of index or something? I'm confused about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with a starting index:

```
>>> {f: n for n, f in enumerate(files, 1)}
{'/var/www/test.jgp': 1, '/var/www/banner.jgp': 2}
```

Just bear in mind that [`dict` objects are inherently unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary). That's obviously fine if you just want the keys numbered in some unspecified order. If, however, you are expecting some particular ordering, you might need a rethink (or [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).

Comment: Starting from Python 3.6, dictionaries are ordered.

Comment: Thanks! It's fine to have them unordered, just needed a number reference for each file.

Comment: @MikeMüller: Good to know, thanks (even if it doesn't help with backwards compatibility here).

Comment: @Yes. But just in case somebody reads this answer in five or ten years, a bit context, i.e. a version number, might help.